# Want to make a button to open an Google Chrome, Cinema 4D etc in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I tried solutions from everywhere, but i got to nowhere Heres you the code

```
namespace Elysium.MetroWindow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Elysium.Controls.Window
    {
        public MainWindow() {}
    }
}
```

And this is the Right Click menu part (Its the [Elysium.Demo](http://www.mediafire.com/?2pib17jc2ey2u8o) Program if anyone want's to see the full App)

```
<Controls:Window.ApplicationBar>
  <Controls:ApplicationBar>
    <!-- Right Click on the UI to open Application Bar -->
    <Controls:DropDownCommandButton  Header="Google Chrome"
                                     ClickMode="Press" />
    <Controls:DropDownCommandButton  Header="Skype"
                                     ClickMode="Press" />
    <Controls:DropDownCommandButton  Header="Microsoft Visual 2012"
                                     ClickMode="Press" />
    <Controls:DropDownCommandButton  Header="Minecraft"
                                     ClickMode="Press" />
    <Controls:DropDownCommandButton  Header="Cinema 4D"
                                     ClickMode="Press" />
    <Controls:DropDownCommandButton  Header="Counter Strike 1.6"
                                     ClickMode="Press" />
  </Controls:ApplicationBar>
</Controls:Window.ApplicationBar>
```

So, how can i add the Right click menu to open a program
I have Tried Process.start("C:\AppPath\Appname.exe")
And the button

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Process Chrome = new Process();

    Chrome.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"; // Needs to be full path
    Chrome.StartInfo.Arguments = ""; // If you have any arguments

    bool result = Chrome.Start();
}
        }
}
```

Comment: `blah blah blah`? Really?

Comment: Add a @ just before  "C:\Program...".

Comment: it won't compile without the `@` anyway

Comment: The button does nothing ..

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any information on what went wrong or if there was an error, but I tried it out (Note my chrome directory was different, so double check the filename) and adding an @ to the file name worked.

```
    Process Chrome = new Process(); //Create the process
    Chrome.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";  // Needs to be full path
    Chrome.StartInfo.Arguments = ""; // If you have any arguments
    Chrome.Start();
```

The `@` symbol allows you to use a reserved keyword but in this example lets you specify a string without having to escape any characters (Using `//` instead of `/`)

Also not sure what the `bool result` was for, but It wasn't nessessary right now.

More information on [Process](http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start)

Comment: I'm an novice, if anyone didn't understand, BUT There was no error, when i debugged it  after i clicked the button. (in debug mode)

First i thought it was the fault that i didn't added the Name="" tag but after i named the button still nothing, i can provide you a link with the project if intrested.

Comment: Add a breakpoint and see if the method is even being called. (On the same line, go to the little gray bar on the left and click it)

Comment: namespace Elysium.MetroWindow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Elysium.Controls.Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Process Chrome = new Process();
            Chrome.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" break;
        }
    }
}

Are you intrested of watching the whole project?

Comment: Not exactly, you need to debug this

Comment: You need the most important part.. `Process.Start` I tried debugging it and it didnt even run the code, so you need to make sure you have registered the click event.

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue how this XAML UI stuff works, I fixed the code for starting the app. You will need to figure out how to make it so when you click the button it runs, because right now there isnt even an event for OnClick.